# is there a way in bash to tell if a directory is new or old?

Tags: git, bash

I have a script, which is rudimentary:

```
set -eux

# We need directories set up.
mkdir -p ~/vagrant/Freya-Factory
mkdir -p ~/vagrant/Freya-Http
mkdir -p ~/vagrant/Freya-Loader
mkdir -p ~/vagrant/Freya-Loader-Assets
mkdir -p ~/vagrant/Freya-Templates

for f in *; do
  if [[ -d $f ]]; then
    cd "$f/"
    git init
    read -e -p "Please enter email for git --global user.email: " email
    git config --global user.email "$email"
    read -e -p "Please enter name for git --global user.name: " name
    git config --global user.email "$name"
    cd ../
  fi
done
```

It will `cd` into each created directory and ask you questions and use those answers to then set up git related information.

But here's the catch. I only want this to `cd` into the directory and do all this if the director is new. But I'm not sure how to check that.

**is there a way in bash to say, if this directory was just created do x, else do y**

**Update**

New means created in the last 1 minute.

Comment: Thats what I was confused about. I would say if it was created in the last 1 minute.

Comment: You'd like to know if a directory contains a Git repository (before you do anything e.g. initializing that directory)? (This is how I interpret your code ATM)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of entering the directory if it's "new",
perhaps a better condition would be to enter if it's not a Git repository.
In any case, `git init` won't make sense inside a Git repository,
and this clears about your dilemma about the definition of "new".

```
for f in */; do
  if [[ -d $f ]] && [[ ! -d $f/.git ]]; then
    cd "$f/"
    git init
    read -e -p "Please enter email for git --global user.email: " email
    git config --global user.email "$email"
    read -e -p "Please enter name for git --global user.name: " name
    git config --global user.email "$name"
    cd ../
  fi
done
```

Actually I recommend rewriting like this:

```
git_init() {
    git init
    read -e -p "Please enter email for git --global user.email: " email
    git config --global user.email "$email"
    read -e -p "Please enter name for git --global user.name: " name
    git config --global user.email "$name"
}

shopt -s nullglob
for f in */; do
  if [[ ! -d $f/.git ]]; then
    (cd "$f/" && git_init)
  fi
done
```

The improvements:

- Using `cd` in scripts is fragile, as you might forget to `cd ..`. By wrapping the `cd` within `(...)`, you don't need to remember, because it's a sub-shell, and directory changes won't affect the parent (current) process
- The glob `*/` matches only directories, so there's no need for the directory check inside the loop. Easier and more efficient too
- The `shopt -s nullglob` is to avoid the case when there are no directories. If there are no directories to match, `*/` will not be expanded, it will be used literally, which would lead to an error. This is a requisite for removing the is-directory check

Answer (score 1):

Best is you have a reference file or directory, say $reference, to compare with - everything newer than $reference is considered new.

```
function birth()
{
   stat -c '%Y' "$1"
}

if [ `birth "$dir"` -gt `birth "$reference"` ]
then
   echo "$dir" is new
else
   echo "$dir" is old
fi
```

'%Y' returns the modification time. For other times, see man stat.

Please be aware of the fact that this is not completely precise - if $dir and $reference have been modified last time in the same second, $dir is considered old. If you need a more precise comparison, find can help you, but it's more work.

Incorporating your latest comment to your own question, I also suggest this:

```
function birth()
{
   stat -c '%Y' "$1"
}

now=`date '+%s'`
old=$((now-60))

if [ `birth "$dir"` -gt $old ]
then
   echo "$dir" is new
else
   echo "$dir" is old
fi
```

Comment: dir will always be modified in terms of contents. I am looking to say if this directory was created more then 1 minute ago, do not run this code, if it was created less then one minute ago, run this code. Its based on creation time stamp then modification, as the modification time stamp would always be changing.

Comment: Well - then you better use '%W' instead of '%Y'